# Google Maps API v3 - Help Linking to Google Marker from Text Link

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps

I have created a google map located at: http://calwestcultural.com/sgs/example_map.html

I am trying to link some text in my spry menu to the left with my google map markers/infowindow.

My javascript is limited as I tried to create ID's for each marker and link to that id but it did not work. I am stumped at this point.

I also would like my markers to display the name when you hover your mouse over it. I achieved this using a different style map but had problems creating markers so the current one I am using above will be my final, I just have to get the links to reference correctly.

PLEASE ANY HELP WITH THIS WOULD GET RID OF MY JS HEADACHE RIGHT NOW!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page shows one way of connecting a sidebar link to your markers

http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/toggle-cats.html

Copying this page's patterns to your case, you need a `gmarkers` global variable

```
//<![CDATA[
var map = null;
var gmarkers = [];
function initialize() {
```

The order in which markers are added matters, they should match the order of the businesses in the sidebar. `gmarkers` will be updated in `createMarker`.

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(37.984798,-121.312094); 
var marker = createMarker(point,'<div style="width:205px"><center><img src="images/sampleuopsign.jpg" /></center><h2>University of the Pacific</h2>3601 Pacific Avenue<br>Stockton, California 95211<br>209.946.2011<br><small>On the web visit: <a href="http://www.pacific.edu">www.Pacific.edu<\/a></small><\/div>')

...

function createMarker(latlng, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
}
```

With the array in place, we can address them by index. Wolfpil simply triggers a click event when a sidebar entry (link) is clicked:

```
function triggerClick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
}
```

And each link can be written like this, replacing 0 and 1 with the order each marker was added:

```
<a href="javascript:triggerClick(0)">Bank of America</a>
<a href="javascript:triggerClick(1)">Bank of Stockton</a>
```

About the marker hover showing a title, the easiest way is adding a `title` option when creating your markers, but it would mean adding a new parameter to your createMarkers function:

```
 function createMarker(latlng, storeName, html) {
  var contentString = html;

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: storeName,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
  });
```

A better alternative in the long run is to use an object for `gmarkers` instead of the array, because adding an item in the middle of the list will disorganize the existing items in the HTML.

Then, places can be called by a string ID, such as `gmarkers['safeway']`. Instead of pushing a marker to the array in `createMarker`, we assign the id to the marker:

```
gmarkers[id] = marker;
```

If you run into trouble write comments below please! I didn't test the code above.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it but my info boxes do not populate: http://www.calwestcultural.com/sgs/example_map.html I simple added the lines stated above and created one link (Bank of America) and another link under PLACES OF INTEREST for the Univesity of P. Just can't get it to work.

Comment: Cut the whole `triggerClick` function from where it is and paste it before this line `function createMarker(latlng, html) {`. The triggerClick function also needs to be global for it to be called from the links. I didn't put too much detail but it matters where each thing is placed.

Comment: Hmmm... ok well i added that function before. I have no code errors according to my dwcs6 app. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I even tried to copy/paste the Wolfpil link but not sure how to apply it to my current map.

Comment: The line needs to use `gmarkers[i]` (with the [i]), not just gmarkers.  `google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");`

Comment: Thanks... i took it out and replaced it but still the trigger does not click...its gotta be something else I am missing.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I made a bad mistake. I finally downloaded your file and tested myself like I should've done in the first place. `gmarkers.push(marker)` has to be inside the `createMarker` function, right after the marker is created. CreateMarker is not returning anything, so leaving gmarkers where I suggested at first adds nothing. I didn't notice that. I updated the answer, please see above.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to remove the `gmarkers.push` where I originally told you to put them (leave only the single one inside createMarker). Otherwise I believe they will throw off the ordering.

Comment: No, I just hack together flimsy solutions. What I gave you was more of an example, in fact, I just thought of the following scenario: What if you wanted to add a new Place of Interest? You'll have to renumber every place that followed it, making it a hassle to add new places. I thought of an alternative solution, where you would write an "ID" to createMarker, and call it like this `gmarkers['univPacific']`, `gmarkers['boa']`, `gmarkers['Safeway']`. It's more typing but in the long run, better, unless you are totally sure that list won't change often. I'll write the alternate answer shortly.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/efeqom/edit#source The changes are `gmarker = {}`, and createMarker having the extra `id` parameter. The links also change, to `javascript:triggerClick('univPacific')` You get to choose the ids so be careful not to write the same id twice, for example, if there are two Safeways in different cities ids need to be different.

Comment: it wont change... this way works fine for what i need it for.

Comment: Alright! Just being overly cautious now. As long as you understand how the code works right now it's all good.